# Apps Script: how to programmatically resize a Google Sheets row with a wrapped cell to be smaller than the wrapped text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a Google spreadsheet in which there are cells with wrapped text that become much too tall. Using Apps Script I would like to resize those rows to be shorter than the wrapped size and I don't see a way.  Anybody know how it can be done?

Comment: AFAIK If you can't do it through UI, Not possible through scripts either.

Comment: @I'-'I That is the answer.